# OpenCV Error: Assertion failed, mat.cpp line 537

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

http://pastebin.com/5ZeMvm2C is my header file in my project.

There are skeleton.at(yaxis,xaxis+1) at line 249. When i type this code in my project i got this error:

```
**OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (dims <= 2 && data && (unsigned)i0 < (unsigned)si
ze.p[0] && (unsigned)(i1*DataType<_Tp>::channels) < (unsigned)(size.p[1]*channel
s()) && ((((sizeof(size_t)<<28)|0x8442211) >> ((DataType<_Tp>::depth) & ((1 << 3
) - 1))*4) & 15) == elemSize1()) in unknown function, file c:\opencv\build\inclu
de\opencv2\core\mat.hpp, line 537**

// mat.cpp line 537 is:
    template<typename _Tp> inline _Tp& Mat::at(int i0, int i1)
        {
            CV_DbgAssert( dims <= 2 && data && (unsigned)i0 < (unsigned)size.p[0] &&
                (unsigned)(i1*DataType<_Tp>::channels) < (unsigned)(size.p[1]*channels()) &&
                CV_ELEM_SIZE1(DataType<_Tp>::depth) == elemSize1());
            return ((_Tp*)(data + step.p[0]*i0))[i1];
        }
```

What's wrong?

http://pastebin.com/gqJ5RpBU is also my .cpp file.

Answer (score 7):

As the error message says, you have an OpenCV runtime assertion that is failed.

As you wrote in your question, the failed assertion is inside the [`Mat::at`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-at) function.

You have to find in your code the call (or the calls) to `Mat::at` that give you the error.

As you can see at the [OpenCV help page](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-at) `Mat::at` is a template function with one, two or three arguments, the failure in the assertion can have various causes:

1. you are using the wrong template parameter (see for example [Using Mat::at(i,j) in opencv for a 2-D Mat object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14303073/using-matati-j-in-opencv-for-a-2-d-mat-object))
2. the arguments are wrong, for example in a call to `template<typename T> T& Mat::at(int i, int j)`, `i` is supposed to be between `0` and the number of rows minus one, `j` is supposed to be between `0` and the number of column minus one. If you have an image with 100 rows and you ask for an element at row 101 the assertion will fail. [Off-by-one errors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) are common in this case.

To be more specific, the assertion failed because at least one of the following `bool`s is `false`:

1. `dims <= 2`
2. `data`
3. `(unsigned)i0 < (unsigned)size.p[0]`
4. `(unsigned)(i1 * DataType<_Tp>::channels) < (unsigned)(size.p[1] * channels())`
5. `CV_ELEM_SIZE1(DataType<_Tp>::depth) == elemSize1())`

The above `bool`s are meaningful inside the scope of `Mat` class.

Furthermore please note that help says that:

> For the sake of higher performance, the index range checks are only
>   performed in the Debug configuration

and so in your Release configuration you will not have the failed assertion but probably a crash somewhere.

From the source you linked, it seems to me that you are on Windows, if that is true and if you have Visual Studio, I suggest you to build OpenCV from the source code, to put a breakpoint inside `Mat::at` and then to debug your code in order to see what of the previous `bool`s is `false`.

Comment: for other readers:you can just put breakpoint on the error line and when it hit,use step into button in VS to go to mat.cpp file and see the value of `data` , `dims` , size.p[0] ,... so you can find which value is causing the error

Answer (score 1):

`Mat::at()` method has been implemented as a template, you must know the type of image before you used the function.

check the channels of the image. 
for single channel image(8UC1), you should manipulate the image pixels as in:

```
image.at<uchar>(row, col) = 255;
```

for three channel color image(8UC3), you should use the function as in:

```
image.at<cv::Vec3b>(row, col)[channel] = 255;
```

if the channel is no problem, you should check the arguments of **the `at(i, j)`, i present the row, j present the col. in other word, i equal to Point.y, j equal to Point.x**.