# OpenCV CV_ELEM_SIZE1(DataType<_Tp>::depth) == elemSize1()

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20217044/opencv-error-assertion-failed-mat-cpp-line-537), my program has a pointer structure to store a 2D array of images as follows

```
Mat*** scaleSpace;
scaleSpace = new Mat**[numOctaves];
scaleSpace[i] = new Mat*[numIntervals];
scaleSpace[i][j] = new Mat_<float>(width, height);
Mat* middle = scaleSpace[i][j];
float currentPixel = middle->at<float>(yi, xi);
```

openCV fires this assert when running the last code line from above.

```
CV_DbgAssert( dims <= 2 && data && (unsigned)i0 < (unsigned)size.p[0] &&
        (unsigned)(i1 * DataType<_Tp>::channels) < (unsigned)(size.p[1] * channels()) &&
        CV_ELEM_SIZE1(DataType<_Tp>::depth) == elemSize1());
```

I found out that the problem is the last expression. All others are `true`.

`CV_ELEM_SIZE1(DataType<_Tp>::depth)` is 4

`elemSize1()` is 1

What are these two values and how do I have to change my program so that both have the same value? Is it a problem that I use float images with only a single channel? Writing this image works perfectly.

```
imwrite(filename, *middle);
```

Comment: Please post an [mcve], because this snippet works ok. Also note that is in general a bad idea to use pointers to `Mat`, since you're likely to broke internal reference counting system

Comment: Since I have absolutely no idea where this error comes from, it's hard for me to post just the code snippets that matter, but I added some that might help. When using pointer is a bad idea, how would you implement a similar structure?

Comment: welcome to row,col land !! `new Mat_<float>(height, width);`