# Passing Mat arguement from Python to c++ method

Tags: python, c++, swig

I tried to Pass the arguments to (c++ opencv ) from my **opencv python** code

Steps I done:

1. Generated .so file for my opencv C++ program by using SWIG
2. Wrote a sample **Opencv Python Program**

A.**Generating .so** for my opencv C++ Code:

1.`swig -c++ -python opencvtest.i`

2`.g++ -fpic -c opencvtest.cpp opencvtest_wrap.cxx -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include/opencv2`

3.`g++ -shared opencvtest.o opencvtest_wrap.o -o _opencvtest.so -L/usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_photo.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_shape.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_stitching.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_superres.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ts.a /usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videostab.so`

4.C++ code

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int sample(Mat image,Mat &out)
{
 int z=0;
    if(! image.data )                              // Check for invalid input
   {
       cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;


   }
  cvtColor(image, out,COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
                                 // Wait for a keystroke in the window
    return z;
}
```

5.Created Wrapper file(opencvtest_wrap.cxx) and **Generated .so file.**

6.Sample python code to call C++ code.

```
 import cv2 , numpy
    import opencvtest
image = cv2.imread('messi5.jpg',0)
    res=opencvtest.sample(image , image1)
    cv2.imshow('Source Image',image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.namedWindow('dst_rt', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.resizeWindow('dst_rt', window_width, window_height)
    cv2.imshow('dst_rt', image1)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    print res
```

I am getting this error when i tried to execute sample.py on my machine

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "sample1.py", line 15, in 
    res=opencvtest.sample(image , image1)

TypeError: **in method 'sample', argument 1 of type 'cv::Mat'**

Any one of the expert can help me to clear the issue.

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28939962/returning-a-opencv-mat-type-from-my-python-code with same problem solved

Answer (score 1):

What is `image` ? I think you have to use types coming from C++ : `opencvtest.Mat`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Now I edited the question.I just read the image in python and pass to c++ code, again get Image from c++ to python. This is flow of above question.I got error at Python wrapper function.function. Pls help me.